# Typescript: Why is it trying to fit argument type against all function overloads?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, functional-programming, monads

I am looking for a typescript guru to help me with this. I am trying to implement some monadic behavior in Typescript. I have a data type that can take 4 distinct shapes. I want to be able to have the basic monadic function like `map` and `flatMap`.

I have been struggling to make the typescript compiler happy about my types and I have tried multiple ways (with classes, abstract classes, simple types etc...) but this is the best thing I came up with.

```
export namespace Data {
  export type Initial<T,E> = { kind: 'initial' }
  export type Loading<T,E> = { kind: 'loading' }
  export type Loaded<T,E> = { kind: 'loaded'; value: T }
  export type Failed<T, E> = { kind: 'failed'; error?: E }
  export type Data<T,E = any> = Failed<T,E> | Loaded<T,E> | Loading<T,E> | Initial<T,E>
  type Kind = Data<any,any>['kind']

  // Instantiations
  export function loadingOf<T=any,E=any>():Loading<T,E> { return {kind: 'loading'}}
  export function initialOf<T=any,E=any>():Initial<T,E> { return {kind: 'initial'}}
  export function loadedOf<T=any,E=any>(value: T):Loaded<T,E> { return {kind: 'loaded', value}}
  export function failedOf<T=any,E=any>(error?: E):Failed<T,E> { return {kind: 'failed', error}}

  // Type guards
  export function isFailed<T,E>( data: Data<T,E>): data is Failed<T,E> { return data.kind === 'failed'}
  export function isLoaded<T,E>( data: Data<T,E>): data is Loaded<T,E> { return data.kind === 'loaded'}
  export function isInitial<T,E>( data: Data<T,E>): data is Initial<T,E> { return data.kind === 'initial'}
  export function isLoading<T,E>( data: Data<T,E>): data is Loading<T,E> { return data.kind === 'loading'}

  // Map
  export function map<T,U,E>(fn: (t: T) => U, data: Loaded<T,E>): Loaded<U,E>;
  export function map<T,U,E>(fn: (t: T) => U, data: Failed<T,E>): Failed<U,E>;
  export function map<T,U,E>(fn: (t: T) => U, data: Loading<T,E>): Loading<U,E>;
  export function map<T,U,E>(fn: (t: T) => U, data: Initial<T,E>): Initial<U,E>;
  export function map<T,U,E>(fn: (t: T) => U, data: Data<T,E>) {
    if(isLoaded(data)) {
      return loadedOf(fn(data.value))
    }
    return data
  }
}

const a = Data.map(x => x, Data.loadedOf('hi'))
const b = Data.map(x => x, Data.loadingOf<string>())
const c = Data.map(x => x, Data.initialOf<string>())
const d = Data.map(x => x, Data.failedOf<string>())
const datas:Data.Data<string>[] = [a,b,c,d]
datas.map(data => Data.map(x=>x, data))
```

This is of course incomplete because typescript is not happy about the map function.

When inspecting the type of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` it is fine. But when trying to do so over an array, it gives this error:

```
Argument of type 'Data<string, any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Initial<string, any>'.
  Type 'Loaded<string, any>' is not assignable to type 'Initial<string, any>'.
    Types of property 'kind' are incompatible.
      Type '"loaded"' is not assignable to type '"initial"'.ts(2345)
```

If I swap the order of overloads it will simply change the last line of the error code from `initial` to something else.

I don't understand why it is not happy about the types. Doesn't `Data<T,E>` fit exactly? Why is it trying to fit the argument type to match all the possible overloads' argument types?

*IF* I remove the signatures with the subtypes and keep only the most generic one then it stops complaining *BUT* it will make the types loose. Any subtype will be coerced to its looser type `Data<T,E>` which is something I don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementation signature does not participate in the overload resolution, as mentioned in the last paragraph on [this page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads).

If you need generic version of `map`, having an implementation with generic signature is not sufficient, you have to add it explicitly, as separate declaration-only overload:

```
export function map<T,U,E>(fn: (t: T) => U, data: Data<T,E>): Data<U, E>;
export function map<T,U,E>(fn: (t: T) => U, data: Data<T,E>) {
    // implementation here....
}
```